# Can I use the latest .NET framework on Windows XP or 7?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, windows-xp

I'm developing an application that must run on Windows XP,7,8 (desktop mode). Which version of .net can I use?

If this version is not a default part of XP or Windows 7, is it a good idea to include it in my application installer?

Comment: Do you mean which framework is supported, or which is installed with the system?

Answer (score 12):

<strike>You can use the latest version of .NET (at the time of writing) on Windows XP.</strike>

.NET 4.5 is not supported on XP. [System requirements for .NET 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30653).

.NET 4.0 is supported on XP.

You should expect to have to install the framework when you install your application though. The [dotNetInstaller](https://github.com/dotnetinstaller/dotnetinstaller) is good for this (although there are other ways too).

There may well be certain classes or methods in the .NET framework that require a higher version of Windows than XP/Vista/7 etc. But you will have to check these case-by-case.