# Build a C# application for Windows Xp with VS2015

Tags: c#

How can I build executables in C# which can be run in Window XP using Visual Studio 2015?
The problem I have now is, that the .exe Visual Studio 2015 creates is not executable under Windows XP.

/*SOLVED*/
Build application with .NET framework 4

Comment: What is the error? What runtime you targeting?

Comment: Select [.NET 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14874076/11683) for your project.

Comment: Yeah this is most likely be down to the .Net framework that your application is targeting. Right click on the project and go to properties. Under the build tab (i think) you should see framework. Ensure it is set to .Net 4 (not 4.5)

Comment: Install .net framework 4.0 in XP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an app for Windows XP using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627628/how-to-create-an-app-for-windows-xp-using-visual-studio-express-2012-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You may try SharpDevelop 4.x with .NET Framework 4, then get a `mysql_connector_net` and reference it from your solution. Done.